# Pre azure start up

Tags: azure, nlog, trace

We are sending all trace logs to our NLog logger. (with a trace listener)
Nlog is configured to work with DryIoC.

Locally this works perfect, however, in Azure (web app), the first trace message is logged, before we could create our DryIoc container. Even a PreAppStartMethodAttribute does not help, as the trace log has occurred even before the PreAppStartMethodAttribute.

Is there a way to do some initialization tasks before azure logs it's first trace message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around by using an async wrapper that prevents NLog from flushing the data until the container/configuration has been initiliazed.